# Passing a string to a modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to grab the string off an object in a table row when it is clicked. I have seen tutorials about getting the string and passing it to synthesized label however I am unable to pass the same string to a synthesized string in my modal view. Is this possible? My code in the parent view is as follows.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Modules *selectedModule;
    selectedModule = [fixedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *moduleComponent = [selectedModule valueForKey:@"name"];

    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated: YES];

    detail.number.text = moduleComponent;

    detail.moduleLabel.text = moduleComponent;



    detail.module = moduleComponent;

}
```

The detail.moduleLabel.text displays correctly however when I try to alert or draw a label using the detail.module I receive null. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated: YES];` after assigning the value to the detail controller.

EDIT:
Another point to note is when exactly do you try to alert it - viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear. Try in the different methods to see what the result is. I apologize but I am unable to test it now and give you the result itself, but have experienced similar behavior (not assigned value) depending on the specific event (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear) where I try to access the value.

Comment: You were it is because I was assigning the value after the message to pushViewController. I made the mistake of assuming that setting the label directly worked in that way so passing the string would as well. Thank you.